# Bubble sort con whiles

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de hacer un bubble sort con array list, usando solo while. Pero no me esta saliendo. 
Estoy tratando de hacer un bubble sort con array list, usando solo while. Pero no me esta saliendo.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> BubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> data) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = data; //Resultado
    boolean swaped = false; //Variable en caso de que no haya intercambio 
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i < result.size() - 1) {
        swaped = false;
        i++;

        while (j < result.size() - i - 1) {

            //obtenemos los valores
            Integer pos = result.get(j);
            Integer next = result.get(j + 1);

            //si la pos es mayor que el siguiente intercambia
            if (pos > next) {
                result.set(j, next);
                result.set(j + 1, pos);
                swaped = true;
            }

            System.out.println(result);
            j++;
        }

        if (!swaped) {//si no hubo intercambio se acaba el método
            break;
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Results:

Before :

```
[13, 7, 18, 5, 2]
[7, 13, 18, 5, 2]
[7, 13, 18, 5, 2]
[7, 13, 5, 18, 2]
```

After :

```
[7, 13, 5, 18, 2]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

---

Estoy tratando de hacer un bubble sort con array list, usando solo while. Pero no me esta saliendo. 
Estoy tratando de hacer un bubble sort con array list, usando solo while. Pero no me esta saliendo.

Este el codigo corregido, pero sigue saliendo los mismo resutados.

```
 public static ArrayList<Integer> BubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> data) {

    ArrayList<Integer> result = data; //Resultado

    boolean swaped = true; //Variable en caso de que no haya intercambio 
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (swaped) {

        swaped = false;
        i++;

        while (j < result.size() - i - 1) {

            //obtenemos los valores
            Integer pos = result.get(j);

            Integer next = result.get(j + 1);

            //si la pos es mayor que el siguiente intercambia
            if (pos > next) {

                result.set(j, next);

                result.set(j + 1, pos);

               // swaped = true;
            }

            System.out.println(result);
            j++;

        }

    }
    return result;

}
```

Before :

`[13, 7, 18, 5, 2]
  [7, 13, 18, 5, 2]
  [7, 13, 18, 5, 2]
  [7, 13, 5, 18, 2]`

After :

`[7, 13, 5, 18, 2]`

`BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que esta mal, no es tu código, es tu algoritmo.

El método burbuja sigue ejecutándose hasta que no haya mas cambios. La cantidad de veces que se ejecuta, es indefinida.

```
boolean swaped = false; //Variable en caso de que no haya intercambio
```

Esta variable es correcta, y tu `while` debe seguir siempre que esta variable sea `true`. mejor, seteala como `true` ;)

```
while (i < result.size() - 1) {
```

Esta linea no tiene ningún sentido. Ahí lo que tenes que controlar es si hubo cambios o no, tu `while` debería ser

```
while (swapped) {
    swaped = false;
```

Recuerda poner `swapped` a true antes de entrar. Y setearlo a `false` exactamente después de entrar, como haces ahora.

Y esto:

```
if (!swaped) {//si no hubo intercambio se acaba el método
    break;
}
```

No tiene ningún sentido. Hace esos cambios, y vas a ver como va a funcionar ;)

Comment: Hice los cambios que sugeriste pero me sale el mismo resutado :(

Comment: Acabo de ver otro error. Pq retornas data? Deberias retornar result! Ahora edito

Comment: Y de paso, edita tu pregunta original. No borres el codigo que ya hiciste, y pone el nuevo codigo. Seguro que hay algo que esta mal. yo no quise escribirte el codigo entero de vuelta, pero de ser necesario lo hago